# How to convert JSON object to specific format

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a JSON like this:

```
var commpanyTags = "[{\"label\":\"Citizen\",\"category\":\"Companies\"},{\"label\":\"Citi Bank\",\"category\":\"Counterparties\"}]";
```

Is it possible to convert it to

```
var commpanyTags = [ { label: "Citizen", category: "Companies" }, { label: "Citi Bank", category: "Counterparties" } ];
```

If it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.parse` ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) will do the job if you are in JavaScript land.

If you are in C#, then consider using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse the JavaScript into a C# object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var commpanyTags = jQuery.parseJSON( commpanyTags );
```